# Failsafes simulations

Tags: arduino, dronekit

I need to simulate failsafes or mechanical failures described in 
[Diagnosing problems](http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-diagnosing-problems-using-logs.html).

Is this possible using SITL/DroneKit ?

Answer (score 0):

On the ArduPilot pages for SITL, you will find various parameters that can be set to control the virtual environment for a simulated drone. Here's the examples: http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/using-sitl-for-ardupilot-testing.html

Command `param show sim*` will show all parameters with name beginning with "sim" which are parameters used by SITL for simulating various conditions. Apart from these, it might also be possible to directly affect vehicle parameters to simulate a deviation in vehicle state relative to input and the desired outcome (like pitch/roll suddently changing to simulate a rotor failure).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

I was thinking about any kind of out-of-the-box unit test , that can be executes to test the releases, or something like that...

Comment: @diegada Maybe if you browse around related projects you'll find some useful test code. But if you're on some new project, then your test cases will likely need to be designed specifically for it.